# SVG path want it to render in circular way

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have a path which represent half of the circle, I want it to render in a circular way.

as it is only path I tried  of svg but it couldn't work.

```html
 <svg version="1.1"  x="0px"
      y="0px" width="131.45px" height="131.451px" viewBox="0 0 131.45 131.451" enable-background="new 0 0 131.45 131.451"
      xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="Group_952" transform="translate(0 0)">
      
    <g id="Path_211">
            <path fill="#0088CE" d="M86.692,128.579l-6.314-20.938c17.843-5.735,29.832-22.563,29.832-41.875
                c0-23.389-17.711-42.625-40.314-43.793l1.059-21.9c33.925,1.752,60.5,30.606,60.5,65.69
                C131.452,94.733,113.463,119.974,86.692,128.579z"/>
        </g>
      <svg>
```

Comment: Your description is a bit broad... Would you have a drawing of what you expect?

Comment: I want that half circle to render in round shape like its making a half circle, this work should done in 1.5s

Comment: Sorry but the question is too broad to receive any quality answer... It would just be shooting in the dark. It seems you are asking to animate this shape with a rotation? Or change the shape? What have you tried, it could help us understand your intent.

Comment: i want to build something like this https://codepen.io/dcondrey/full/pwEdH.but it starts from bottom i want mine to start from top and make a half circle hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 7):

Your semicircle is drawn using a double path see image below

[image]

Therefore, you can animate figure drawing only with the help of `filter` or`mask`

I suggest using the technique of drawing a figure from the top point to a semicircle, by changing the 'stroke-dasharray' of the middle line of the figure.

[image]

The middle line turned out - a circle with the center of `(70.70)` and a radius of `50`

Next, set `stroke-width ="20"` and `stroke-dasharray = "157 157"` to get half the circle

Turn the semicircle counterclockwise 90 degrees so that its beginning is at the top

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="131.45px" height="131.451px" viewBox="0 0 131.45 131.451"  >  
    
 <circle transform="rotate(-90 70 70)" cx="70" cy="70" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#0088CE"
    stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="157 157">
    
 </circle>
</svg>
```

To animate the drawing from the top point to half the circle, change the `stroke-dasharray` `from ="0 314" to ="157 157"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="131.45px" height="131.451px" viewBox="0 0 131.45 131.451"  >  
    
 <circle transform="rotate(-90 70 70)" cx="70" cy="70" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#0088CE"
    stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="157 157">
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 314;157 157"
   dur="5s"
   fill="freeze" /> 
 </circle>
</svg>
```

### CSS animation

```css
 .crc1 {
 fill:none;
 stroke:#0088CE;
 stroke-width:20;
 stroke-dasharray:157.07;
 animation: dash 4s ;
 }
 @keyframes dash {
 0% {stroke-dasharray:  0 314}
 100% {stroke-dasharray: 157 157}
 }
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="131.45px" height="131.451px" viewBox="0 0 131.45 131.451" >  
    
 <circle class="crc1" transform="rotate(-90 70 70)" cx="70" cy="70" r="50"> </circle>
 
</svg>
```

**Semicircle rotation animation**

For animation the change of attribute `stroke-dashoffset` is used:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="131.45px" height="131.451px" viewBox="0 0 131.45 131.451"  >  
    <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#EDEDED"
    stroke-width="20" /> 
    
 <circle transform="rotate(-90 70 70)" cx="70" cy="70" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#0088CE"
    stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="157.07" stroke-dashoffset="-314">
    <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
  values="0;-314"
  dur="2s"
  repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
    
 </circle>
</svg>
```

**Complex animation of drawing and rotation**

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="131.45px" height="131.451px" viewBox="0 0 131.45 131.451"  >  
    <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#EDEDED"
    stroke-width="20" /> 
    
 <circle transform="rotate(-90 70 70)" cx="70" cy="70" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#0088CE"
    stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="157.07" stroke-dashoffset="-314">
  <animate id="an_dasharray"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 314;157 157"
   begin="0s;an_dashoffset.end+0.5s"
   dur="2s"
   fill="freeze" />  
  <animate id="an_dashoffset"
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
  values="0;-314"
  begin="an_dasharray.end"
  dur="2s"
  repeatCount="2" /> 
     
 </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for a pie chart-like progressive completion animation? Like going from 0 to 50% and another that goes from 50% to 100%, both at the same time, but not based on stroke but the shape itself. (think two semi-circles completing each other)